# A bijection from $\{x: h(x)=\frac{1}{5}\}$ to $\mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Question :
Assume that every rational number is written in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $(p,q)=1$ and $q \gt 0$.

For every rational number, The function $h(x)$ is defined like this :
$x=\frac{p}{q} \implies h(x)=\frac{1}{q}$

Prove that $S_1:=\{x:h(x)=\frac{1}{5}\}$ is an infinite countable set.

My way :

I think that $S_1$ is equal to $\{\frac{p}{5}:(p,5)=1\}$. So,
I defined a function called $f$ which operates on each member of $S_1$ in this way :

$\forall \frac{p}{5} \in S_1 \space\space\space f(\frac{p}{5}) = p$
( First thing i'm stuck on, is to prove that $f(x)$ is surjective. )

Then i defined another function called $g$ from $\mathbb N$ to  $\mathbb Z-\{x: \exists k \in \mathbb Z \space \space \space x=5k\}$  which behaves this way :

Foreach $n \in \mathbb N$ If $\space\space\space \exists k \in \mathbb Z \space\space\space n=5k$ , $g(n)=$the first negative number in $\mathbb Z$
which is not in the form of $5k$ and is not taken by another number in $\mathbb N$.

If $n$ is not in the form of $5k$ , $g(n)=n$.

So, we have :

$g(1)=1 , g(2)=2 , g(3)=3 , g(4)=4$.

$5$ is in the form of $5k$, So we take the first available negative number in $\mathbb Z$, which is $-1$. $f(5)=-1$.

$g(6)=6, g(7)=7 , g(8)=8 , g(9)=9 $.

$10$ is in the form of $5k$, So $g(10)=-2$.

And so on ...

Then , If we show that $g$ is bijective, There will be a function like $g^{-1}$ from  $\mathbb Z-\{x: \exists k \in \mathbb Z \space \space \space x=5k\}$ to $\mathbb N$.
So, by putting these all together, we will conclude that $g^-1(f(x))$ is a bijective function from $S_1$ to $\mathbb N $.

My problem is that i don't know how to accurately define these functions $f , g$.

Comment: You define $h(\frac pq)=\frac 1p$ but then you appear to claim that $f(\frac p5)=\frac 15$, which is different.  Did you mean to say $h(\frac pq)=\frac 1q$?  Also...are you required to exhibit a bijection or would it suffice to exhibit a countable subset of $S_1$?  The latter is a lot easier (just use $\frac 5{2^n}$  or $\frac {2^n}5$ depending on what you meant for $h(x)$).

Comment: @lulu  oh, that's my mistake ... i'll make edit ... and about the second thing you said, if you have a better way, i'll be glad to see it :)

Comment: The set of numbers coprime to $5$ are infinite.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yeah, I know that ... but i should prove it first ...

Comment: @IStillHaveHope It's obvious. Even a child understands that the set of numbers not ending in $0$ or $5$ are infinite. For a formal proof, fix a prime $p \neq 5$ and consider $p^k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This is an infinite set of numbers coprime to $5$. Alternatively, you could take numbers of the form $5n + 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we have $$S_1:=\left\{x:h(x)=\frac{1}{5}\right\}=\left\{\dfrac{5}{p}:gcd(p,5)=1\right\}$$

Now define $$f:S_1\to \mathbb{N}, \dfrac{5}{p}\to p-\left[\frac{p}{5}\right].$$ Check that $f$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

We already have a 1 to 1 mapping from the rationals to h by definition of h. we know the rationals are countable, therefore the set constructed by members of h are countable. to show that it is infinite it suffices to say that there are infinite primes p not equal to 5 and take 5/p through the definition to show we have all primes are in the set therefore it is countably infinite.